# How can I add a method to JQuery tab widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to extend the jQuery UI `tabs` widget by adding a method to all its instances.

I've tried both `$.extend()` and `jQuery.widget()`, but when invoking the method in a instance of tabs the method is still `undefined`.

I double checked that the definition occurred before the method call.

Here is my last attempt:

```
jQuery.widget( 'tabs', $.ui.tabs, {
    showInTab: function (title, url) {
        window.alert(title + ": " + url);
    }
});
```

Can you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "tabs" to "ui.tabs" it hopefully starts working.

```
jQuery.widget( 'ui.tabs', $.ui.tabs, {
    showInTab: function (title, url) {
        window.alert(title + ": " + url);
    }
});
```

JsFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/rpQTn/2/